# jquery/JS plugin to detect URL in textarea and wrap in <a> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I really don't want to have to reinvent the wheel with this one.  There must be a plugin available to do this?

What I want is for a url to be detected as the user is typing into a textarea.  Then once they have pressed 'space' and completed the url, wrap it in an  tag and make it a genuine link.

A quick google hasn't turned up anything useful.  Hopefully someone will know of a good solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complex feature that I've played with for some time now. As far as I know nobody has  a robust and "sexy" solution for this. The typical solution is to use some sort of editor instead of a textarea.

My solution was to create a DIV behind the textarea (lower z-index) and use jquery linkify on that div. A keyup event in the textarea copies all the text into the div. That will generate realtime links in the div. The new problem then was making those clickable. Afterall the div was behind in z-index. My workable solution to that problem was to flip the z-index back-and-forth on mousemove .

I really miss a good solution to this myself. My own solution has its flaws...

Comment: I see... Looks like i'll have to go at it myself then.  I'm extremely surprised no one has come up with anything yet, I would have thought it was a very much in demand feature.  Anyway, huge  thanks for the info and for pointing me in the right direction with jquery linkify

Answer (score 0):

I found this https://github.com/stephan-fischer/jQuery-LiveUrl this morning. Looks pretty good as a stand alone JQuery implementation.